# Unable to use environment variable for Maven Proxy port

Tags: linux, maven, maven-3

I am able to configure a proxy to work successfully with Maven using **settings.xml**.

I decided to take the configuration one step further and use environment variables for each of the proxy's parameters like so:

```
<proxies>
  <proxy>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>https</protocol>
    <host>${env.PROXY_HOST}</host>
    <port>${env.PROXY_PORT}</port>
    <username>${env.PROXY_USER}</username>
    <password>${env.PROXY_PASSWORD}</password>
  </proxy>
</proxies>
```

This configuration - specifically using an environment variable for port - causes my Maven execution to break. First it passes this warning:

```
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[WARNING] Unable to parse element 'port', must be an integer (position: END_TAG seen ...<port>${env.PROXY_PORT}</port>... @29:40) caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${env.PROXY_PORT}" @conf/settings.xml, line 29, column 40
[WARNING]
```

and the execution fails soon after with an incorrect port:

```
org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataTransferException: 
Connect to localhost:0 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

---

Maven is able to parse the environment variables for host, user & password in proxy settings, however not for port.

Here is an example for how the environment variable is set in a bash script, which is then followed by the Maven command

```
PROXY_PORT=8888
export PROXY_PORT
```

I've also tried:

```
PROXY_PORT="8888"
export PROXY_PORT
```

---

Why isn't the port setting using the environment variable like the other proxy settings?

How can I use environment variables for the proxy port setting?

Comment: The variable  is `PROXY_PORT`, but you're exporting `LD_PROXY_PORT`.

Comment: Get rid of `LD_` in the `export` command

Comment: @Barmar typo from my post. I still get the same issue. Apologies! Updated

Comment: Now I can't see a reason for it. Does it work if you hard-code `8888` in the settings file?

Comment: The error message indicates that it's not trying to do the `${...}` substitution at all. Very strange that it would only fail for that one line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a maven reported bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6401 (or here: https://github.com/apache/maven/pull/163#issuecomment-390888715 )

The substitution is done for the host:

```
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>https</protocol>
      <host>${PROXY_HOST}</host>
      <port>${PROXY_PORT}</port>
      <username>${PROXY_USER}</username>
      <password>${PROXY_PASSWORD}</password>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
```

Which is substituted like this:

```
$ PROXY_PORT=100 PROXY_HOST=http://thehost PROXY_USER=TheUser PROXY_PASSWORD=ThePassword mvn help:effective-settings | grep -FA8  '<proxies>'
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <protocol>https</protocol>
      <username>TheUser</username>
      <password>***</password>
      <port>0</port>
      <host>http://thehost</host>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
```